# I can't change the font of the text

Tags: c, winapi, fonts

I want to change the font of the text that the user enters in the text field. Here is path of my code:

```
HWND Edit = CreateWindowEx(...);
HFONT hfont = CreateFont(12, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, "MS Sans Serif");
SendMessage(Edit, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hfont), TRUE);
```

But I get some strange error. Strange, because everyone on the Internet uses this method and apparently everyone is fine. Here is error message from gcc:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\winapi>gcc main.c
main.c: In function 'WinMain':
main.c:86:32: error: expected expression before 'WPARAM'
  SendMessage(Edit, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hfont), TRUE);
                                ^~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windef.h:42:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:42,
                 from main.c:1:
main.c:86:2: error: too few arguments to function 'SendMessageA'
  SendMessage(Edit, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hfont), TRUE);
  ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:48:0,
                 from main.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\winuser.h:4157:27: note: declared here
 WINUSERAPI LRESULT WINAPI SendMessageA (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What are some ways to fix this?

Comment: If you don't use WPARAM(), does it complain about invalid cast?

Comment: #pragma comment(lib,"Gdi32.lib") (Please get rid of MinGW)

Comment: #pragma comment(lib,"Gdi32.lib") didn't change everything.

Comment: _Please get rid of MinGW_. But there are no alternatives.

Comment: How about Visual Studio?

Comment: In VS C++, which is also C#-like. I need to use pure C. If I wanted to write GUI in C++, I would use Qt.

Comment: Visual Studio also supports pure C. It's not only for GUI. Also, you are already using gui calls by using fonts and edit box. If you assume that you would create something good with poor stuff like Mingw or Qt you are wasting time. Serious Windows developing requires Visual Studio.

Comment: I think you need to learn the language. That's not how you cast. It's `(WPARAM)hfont`. My guess is you are reading Delphi code, because that's how you'd cast it there. Also, you are fine with mingw.

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't see any _pure C_ option [link](https://imgur.com/FzLqd8j)

Comment: cl can compile C code. By default files with the extension .c are treated as such. The standards support has traditionally been poor but that is changing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference between C++ and C, in C it needs to be:

```
SendMessage(Edit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, TRUE);
```

Even when presenting winapi code most non-Microsoft samples are likely to assume using C++ compilation.